# Quartz.NET (Clustered) with ADOJobStore going to TRIGGER_STATE ERROR without any error logged

Tags: logging, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I am using Quartz.NET 2.3.2 - Clustered Mode with ADOJobStore. It is having 8 jobs with a simple trigger for each. All the jobs are configured with [DisallowConcurrentExecution].

The issue I am facing is - After a couple of hours of run (sometimes 30 minutes) , some of the jobs go into TRIGGER_STATE ERROR (queried QRTZ_TRIGGERS tables) without logging any error information in quartz log file. Pl find the relevant sections of quartz.server.exe.config below.

Also currently to isolate this issue - I am currently running Quartz from one server only (recreated schema).

To add more information - All the jobs "Execute" method have a main try-catch to prevent any exception reach Quartz-Core. Let me know if this has to be changed. I have been reading about using "JobExecutionExecution" in Job.Execute catch area. I am not sure about its usage.

```
    <common>
        <logging>
          <factoryAdapter type="Common.Logging.Log4Net.Log4NetLoggerFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging.Log4Net1213">
            <arg key="configType" value="INLINE"/>
          </factoryAdapter>
        </logging>
    </common>

<log4net>
  <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%d [%t] %-5p %l - %m%n"/>
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <appender name="EventLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender">
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%d [%t] %-5p %l - %m%n"/>
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <appender name="QuartzInternalLog" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="Trace/QuartzInternalLogFile_%date{yyyyMMdd}.txt"/>
    <appendToFile value="true"/>
    <maximumFileSize value="1024KB"/>
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="1000" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
    <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%d{HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n"/>
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="Log/ABCXYZIntService_%date{yyyyMMdd}.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="2" />
    <maximumFileSize value="1MB" />
    <rollingStyle value="Date" />
    <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] – %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <appender name="SmtpAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SmtpAppender">
    <to value="admin@abc.com" />
    <from value="admin@abc.com" />
    <subject value="Sample Subject" />
    <smtpHost value="smtp.abc.com" />
    <bufferSize value="512" />
    <lossy value="true" />
    <evaluator type="log4net.Core.LevelEvaluator">
      <threshold value="WARN"/>
    </evaluator>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%newline%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <logger name="ErrorLogger">
    <level value="All" />
    <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
  </logger>
  <logger name="EmailLogger">
    <level value="Error" />
    <appender-ref ref="SmtpAppender" />
  </logger>


  <logger name="Quartz">
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="QuartzInternalLog" />
  </logger>

</log4net>
<!-- 
    We use quartz.config for this server, you can always use configuration section if you want to.
    Configuration section has precedence here.  
  -->
<quartz>
  <add key="quartz.checkConfiguration" value="false"/>
  <add key="quartz.server.serviceName" value="ABC"/>
  <add key="quartz.server.serviceDisplayName" value="ABC"/>
  <add key="quartz.server.serviceDescription" value="ABC"/>
  <add key="quartz.scheduler.instanceName" value="ABCScheduler"/>
  <add key="quartz.scheduler.instanceId" value = "AUTO"/>
  <add key="quartz.threadPool.type" value="Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz"/>
  <add key="quartz.threadPool.threadCount" value="10"/>
  <add key="quartz.threadPool.threadPriority" value="Normal"/>
  <add key="quartz.plugin.xml.type" value="Quartz.Plugin.Xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin, Quartz"/>
  <add key="quartz.plugin.xml.fileNames" value="~/quartz_jobs.xml"/>
  <add key="quartz.scheduler.exporter.type" value="Quartz.Simpl.RemotingSchedulerExporter, Quartz"/>
  <add key="quartz.scheduler.exporter.port" value="555"/>
  <add key="quartz.scheduler.exporter.bindName" value="QuartzScheduler"/>
  <add key="quartz.scheduler.exporter.channelType" value="tcp"/>
  <add key="quartz.scheduler.exporter.channelName" value="httpQuartz"/>
  <add key="quartz.jobStore.type" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz"/>
  <add key="quartz.jobStore.dataSource" value="default"/>
  <add key="quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix" value="QRTZ_"/>
  <add key="quartz.jobStore.clustered" value="true"/>
  <add key="quartz.jobStore.lockHandler.type" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.SimpleSemaphore, Quartz"/>
  <add key="quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.StdAdoDelegate, Quartz"/>
  <add key="quartz.dataSource.default.provider" value="SqlServer-20"/>
  <add key="quartz.jobStore.useProperties" value="true"/>
  <add key="quartz.jobStore.selectWithLockSQL" value="SELECT * FROM {0} LOCKS UPDLOCK WHERE LOCK_NAME = @ lockName"/>
  <add key="quartz.dataSource.default.connectionStringName" value="QuartzStore"/>
  <add key="quartz.dataSource.default.connectionString" value="Data Source=MyServer;Initial Catalog=MyDB;User ID=test;Password=test"/>
</quartz>

<appSettings>
      <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. This issue was in our UAT environment. There was another Quartz job service in SIT environment which was pointing to the Quartz database of UAT environment. This might be causing contention issues.

This url gave me a hint - 
http://forums.terracotta.org/forums/posts/list/4317.page